# How do I update children in a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have a model called Tournament, which `has_many` Entries. There is a method in Tournament called `reset_rankings`, which traverses all of its entries and updates the `current_rank` field of each entry based on how many points that entry currently has. I call `entry.save` on each entry I update in this traversal.

This method seems to update the entries in memory just fine, but when I `reload` the Tournament I was working with, the `current_rank` fields all revert to what they were before calling `reset_rankings`.

I tried calling `tournament.save` after calling `reset_rankings` but that still didn't persist the changes

I am sure I am doing something stupid, but the rails magic isn't working like I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call entry.save, are you checking the return value? If false then the save was blocked for some reason, eg didn't pass your validations.

Or change foo.save to foo.save! to raise an error when the save fails.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. The save was failing due to a validation.

Comment: Happy to have helped. Many have been caught by this issue, including me. Remember that validations can be written to only fire on create, vs on every save. Also, you can an "experts mode" or "reset mode" in your validations: check the value of a instance variable in your validations. Then only set the instance variable when the model is in reset mode. Etc.